# Why does my redux initial state store another array from my database (MongoDB)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm making a goal setter app inspired from Brad Traversy's MERN stack guide but instead, I used NextJS w/ TypeScript instead of just plain ReactJS since I want to get my feet wet on those as well as I learn MERN.

My problem is that my Redux state: goals keeps on storing another array variable that's named goals and actually has the goals which I need to map on my frontend.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import goalService from "./goalService";

type stateTypes = {
  goals: any[];
  isError: boolean;
  isSuccess: boolean;
  isLoading: boolean;
  message: String;
};

const initialState: stateTypes = {
  goals: [],
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
};

export const addGoal = createAsyncThunk(
  "goals/add",
  async (goalData, thunkAPI: any) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await goalService.addGoal(goalData, token);
    } catch (error: any) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

// Get user goals
export const getGoals = createAsyncThunk(
  "goals/getAll",
  async (_, thunkAPI: any) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await goalService.getGoals(token);
    } catch (error: any) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

export const goalSlice = createSlice({
  name: "goal",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(addGoal.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(addGoal.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.goals.push(action.payload);
      })
      .addCase(addGoal.rejected, (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getGoals.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getGoals.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.goals = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getGoals.rejected, (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const { reset } = goalSlice.actions;
export default goalSlice.reducer;
```

Here is a screenshot from my react devtools showing the tree of goals:

[image]

I cloned Brad Traversy's code in my PC but it seems to have no problem about this as I tried to run his code and I even tried copying to how he coded it but to no avail, the problem still persists to mine. I hope someone can see this and help me.

[image]

I need the answer to this cause I can't map my state: goals as it just contains another array.